# player 2d rotation

Tags: unity, 2d, rotation

Hello i have one problem with my 2d game a made 2d endles racing game and i add cars spawner with prefab and on this scripts i add and coin whith box collider 2d and make trigger and when i play the game when i take the coin my car is rotation on z where is my problem here my code.
[image: Start Game]
[image: After Play Game]

```css
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class carSpawner : MonoBehaviour {

 public GameObject[] cars;
 int carNo;
 public float maxPos = 1.7f;
 public float delayTimer;
 float timer;

 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () {

  timer = delayTimer;

 }
 
 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update () {

  timer -= Time.deltaTime;
  if (timer <= 0) {

   Vector3 carPos = new Vector3 (Random.Range (-1.7f, 1.7f), transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
   carNo = Random.Range (0, 10);
   Instantiate (cars[carNo], carPos, transform.rotation);
   timer = delayTimer;

  }
   
 
 }
}
```

```css
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col) {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "coin")
        {
            col.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't really understand your problem, that being said, the Z rotation looks really minimum, it probably has something to do with the car controller script.
If you don't want to rotate on the Z axis at all, just mark this inside your car's rigidbody.

[image]